# relationship can't be changed , foreign-keys are non-nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I'm running an (old) MVC3 web app on an MSSQL DB, utilizing EF 6.0 code first and the repository pattern.

the system has been running in production for the last 7 years (EF was updated about 1 year ago).

I've been encountering a very strange exception in 1 particular area of the system.
when attempting to create or update certain entities, I encounter the following exception:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

here's one of the problematic entities:

```
public class BeaconAppErrorLog

    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int EntityId { get; set; }
        public string RawJson { get; set; }
        public DateTime SavedAt { get; set; }

        public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }    
        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }

        public int? ContainerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ContainerId")]
        public Container Container { get; set; }

        public int? DailyTrackId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DailyTrackId")]
        public DailyTrack DailyTrack { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public string Error { get; set; }
    }
```

here's the code for creation & saving :

```
 DataContext.BeaconAppErrorLogs.Add(new BeaconAppErrorLog()

                    {
                        EntityId = 2,
                        SavedAt = DateTime.Now,
                        EmployeeId = activity.EmployeeId,
                        DailyTrackId = activity.DailytrackId,
                        Error = error
                    });


DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

the 'EmployeeId' and 'DailyTrackId' fields are foreign keys, they receive 
valid values (i.e id's that correspond to the respective entity and exist in the DB)

an almost identical code is written hundreds of time throughout the application - and is functioning properly (even for the exact same entity).

I have no idea what is going on and why, and so far all of the solutions I've attempted did not work.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Nir

Comment: Can you show the Mapping code, or best the structure in the database?

Comment: @Nikolaus what do you mean by 'mapping code' or structure in the DB'?  the class is the entity as created in the DB by the EF code-first

Comment: are you certain EF isn't tracking any other entities at the time `SaveChanges` is called that would cause this error? you can call db.savechanges before adding the entity and see if the same exception is thrown to test this. id also take a look at teh db and ensure teh FKs are defined as nullable just as a sanity check

Comment: i reformulate Greg comment: are you sure that the `SaveChanges` only insert a new row in the log table ?

Comment: I mean the Migrations, for example and GregH asked, is it possible, that any other Entity is Tracked, that causes the error?

Comment: thanks, @GregH and tschmit007 - you were right. I'll add an answer to this post

Answer (score 0):

turns out the solution was someplace else entirely.
as @gregH and @tschmit007 have pointed out, EF tracks changes in entities.
once we've started moving the 'DataContext.SaveChanges()' command higher up the execution chain we've found that changes being made to one of the entities higher up were causing the issue.
the actual problem was a modification of a child collection property to the DailyTrack entity. the modification consisted of filtering the collection data (a LINQ WHERE Claus performed on the collection).

thanks, everyone for your help.